# How to replace na with 0

Tags: r

Sorry, I'm a complete beginner.
I want the data of a certain table, but because I divide 0 by 0, I get NA. How can I change NA to 0?

```
india$ruppi.per.hourwork<-india$Family_Labour__Rs__/india$Family_Labour__Hrs__
```

This is what I did to add a column, what can be done to change NA to 0?

analyzed a large data set using division, I tried to divide 0 by 0, it caused me a `NaN‘ error, how can I replace the error with 0

Comment: Is it `NA` or `NaN`? have a look at `x = c(0L, 2L, NaN, NA); x[is.nan(x)] = 0L; x`. There is also a function called `is.na()`. Does this get you started?

Comment: The question is not completely clear. What if the division by zero is `1/0`? In this case the result is an infinity, `Inf`. Is the only case to be addressed `0/0`?

Comment: it is NaN i think Because I try to divide 0/0.  I  want that this error will change to 0

Comment: Try `india$ruppi.per.hourwork[is.nan(india$ruppi.per.hourwork)] = 0L` then.

Answer (score 3):

I would actually use `ifelse()` to entirely avoid the divide by zero:

```r
india$ruppi.per.hourwork <- ifelse(india$Family_Labour__Hrs__ == 0,
                                   0,
                                   india$Family_Labour__Rs__ / india$Family_Labour__Hrs__)
```

Comment: What about `1/0`? (A case not in the question, maybe off-topic.)

Comment: @RuiBarradas Based on my reading of the original question, the issue is divide by zero with _any_ numerator.